# Save file in document directory in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I am saving files in a document directory in swift 3 with this code:

```
fileManager = FileManager.default
// let documentDirectory = fileManager?.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as String
var path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
path = path + name

let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Notifications")
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
let bool = fileManager?.createFile(atPath: path, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)

print("bool is \(bool)")
return true
```

But as you can see, I am not using `filemanager` to get document directory path as `filemanager` gives only URL not string.

Questions:

- How to get string from file manager?
- Is there any chance of crash in my code?

Comment: `let fileManager = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.path`

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Please think the other way round.

`URL` is the recommended way to handle file paths because it contains all convenience methods for appending and deleting path components and extensions – rather than `String` which Apple has removed those methods from.

You are discouraged from concatenating paths like `path = path + name`. It's error-prone because you are responsible for all slash path separators.

Further you don't need to create a file with `FileManager`. `Data` has a method to write data to disk.

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
do {
    let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
    let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(name)
    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Notifications")
    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
        try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
        return true
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
return false
```

Alternatively make the function `throw` and hand over the error to the caller

```
func saveFile(with name: String) throws {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(name)
    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Notifications")
    guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { throw URLError(.cannotDecodeContentData) }
    try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
}
```

In iOS 16+, macOS 13+ there is a more convenient way to get the URL to the documents directory without `FileManager`

```
let documentDirectory = URL.documentsDirectory
```

Comment: A check `if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path) {
                print("File already there")
            }` Should be there.

Comment: Can i save whole folder with images in document directory ?

Comment: @KhushbuDesai Yes, I suppose.

Comment: @vadian Can you please help me with this? I will share my Code, My folder is copied in doc directory but without data.

Comment: What is going on here:
'let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Notifications")'

What does resourceName represent?

Comment: @Moondra Please read https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/be-literal-76e9b4389eda

Comment: @jack https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/97497 --> "it is generally regarded s incorrect" etc. What's your take on this?

Answer (score 5):

following the above example given by vadian the only line you need to save a (Data)file in Document Directory is:

> try imageData.write(to: fileURL)

Getting the file path is the interesting part

ex: create the file path

```
 func createNewDirPath( )->URL{ 

let dirPathNoScheme = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String

    //add directory path file Scheme;  some operations fail w/out it
    let dirPath = "file://\(dirPathNoScheme)"
    //name your file, make sure you get the ext right .mp3/.wav/.m4a/.mov/.whatever
    let fileName = "thisIsYourFileName.mov"
    let pathArray = [dirPath, fileName]
    let path = URL(string: pathArray.joined(separator: "/"))

    //use a guard since the result is an optional
    guard let filePath = path else {
        //if it fails do this stuff:
        return URL(string: "choose how to handle error here")!
    }
    //if it works return the filePath
    return filePath
}
```

call the function:

```
let shinnyNewURLpath = createNewDirPath( ) 


//write data to file using one line in do/catch operation
do {
   try yourDataObject?.write(to: shinnyNewURLpath)
    } 
catch {
       print("catch error",error.localizedDescription)
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

I use the following method for creating "Test.txt" file. Hope it helps you.

```
func createFile() {
    let fileName = "Test"
    let documentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let fileURL = documentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("txt")
    print("File PAth: \(fileURL.path)")
}
```